# Server configuration planning to run a Laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need details how much Memory will be required for each of the following in the server so that I could purchase one as per my need.
1) Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM )
2) Laravel Framework 5.2
3) Mysql 5.6
4) PHP 7.0
5) PHP 5.6
Which will help to chose the RAM size depending on the need. I need reference document also if possible.

Comment: For stipulate how much of resources your server will need, you have to give us some information about how many clients (or users) your system will have to handle...

Comment: that depends on your application (memory usage per request) and the number of requests per second.

Comment: May be for now I have 10 active users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This purely depends on the following

- How much clients or users you have.
- How much of them will be always active or online
- What kind of information is retrieved that is how much data is
  processed
- It also depends on many more facts

Even saying approximation is not possible with out analyzing this

But for a simple start up machine for testing Forge like tools configure with 1 GiB RAM - 1 vCPU